# Data processing for clustering analyses

Tags: python, data-science, data-processing

I try to prepare my dataset for cluster analyses like k-Means or BIRCH algorithm. I don't know how-to start with the preparation and find, for example, outliner or something else. I hope you can help me.

My dataset is a dataframe and has the following columns:

```
A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | iO
```

With `df.describe(include = "all")`  I get the following datas:

```
         A1             | A2            | A3            |A4             | iO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
count    15372.000000    15372.000000    15372.000000    15372.000000    15372
unique   NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN             2
top      NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN             True
freq     NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN             14935 
mean     145.570554      35.750641       64.284180       49.225190       NaN
std      5134.725533     1709.696386     2433.688046     2380.091285     NaN
min      0.436000        0.353000        0.353000        -0.000000       NaN
25%      1.000000        1.920000        2.000000        1.690000        NaN
50%      1.970000        2.000000        3.860000        2.000000        NaN
75%      3.984000        3.907000        6.957000        3.883000        NaN
max      200990.260000   200072.157000   200992.243000   200992.243000   NaN
```

The median of each column is:

```
A2: 2.00
A3: 3.86
A4: 2.0
iO: 1.0
```

In the normal case the values of A1,A2,A3 and A4 are between 2 and 5.

Further I want to use this dataframe for clustering analyses. In my dataframe is "iO" a result of the usecase and A1, A2, A3 and A4 has an impact on the result.

I hope you can help me to prepare my data.

Best regards
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple method is to use Z-Score.
import numpy as np
outliers=[]
def detect_outlier(column_data_array):

```
threshold=3
mean_1 = np.mean(column_data_array)
std_1 =np.std(column_data_array)


for y in data_1:
    z_score= (y - mean_1)/std_1 
    if np.abs(z_score) > threshold:
        outliers.append(y)
return outliers
```

Or you can use IRQ-Score

Comment: Alex, thank you for your answer. What does "data_1" mean? What is in it?